# Split a text file into multiple files, beyond the {99} limit of csplit

Tags: osx, csplit

I'd like to split the contents of a .txt file into multiple files, but I'm encountering two questions about limitations of csplit:

(1) can anyone offer a way around csplit's maximum limit of '99' file splits?  I have a file with up to 384 splits based on a recurring blank line or character.  I'd like csplit to be able to accomodate this with {*}, but this exceeds csplit's intrinsic file generation capacity.

(2) does anyone know of a way to pass the contents of a file to csplit (pipe to csplit), or can csplit only be used in its conventional way of calling a file in place?  i.e. `csplit -f split_name file_to_split.txt /split/ {*}` vs. `[series of commands] | csplit -f split_name /split/ {*}`

Thank you for any suggestions, or alternatives to accomplish a similar task.

Comment: What csplit implementation do you have? Does it work if you supply a longer suffix format explicitly e.g. `-b '%03d'`?

Comment: Good questions...I must not have gnu csplit (Mac OS 10.9.5), because csplit in my command line doesn't accept pipes and has the 99-piece limit.  How can gnu csplit be implemented?  @steeldriver, what is meant by supplying a longer suffix format explicitly?

Comment: OSX `csplit` reads from stdin too, check your man page: `If file is a dash ('-'), csplit reads from standard input.` You can get `gnu coreutils` on mac via homebrew, google for more details.

Comment: BSD `csplit` doesn't have `{*}` at all, but it does have the POSIX `-n` option, `Use number decimal digits to form filenames for the file pieces`, which I just tested and it seems to work when you give the appropriate repetition count.

Answer (score 8):

[As Michael Homer remarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272221/split-a-text-file-into-multiple-files-beyond-the-99-limit-of-csplit#comment472555_272221), any POSIX-compliant csplit can take more than 99 files, but you have to pass the `-n` option.

```
csplit -n 3 file_to_split.txt
```

This being said, if you have a task that can be done easily with the GNU version of csplit but not with the FreeBSD/OSX version, you can install the GNU version (part of GNU coreutils). GNU coreutils can be installed through several sources, I think the most popular is [homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_management_software)). See also [How to replace Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities).

Alternatively, most of what csplit does can be implemented in a few lines of awk, and that gives you more flexibility in terms of things like the output file name. The following snippet reads from standard input and writes lines to `part-000.txt`, `part-001.txt`, etc., changing files every time a line contains `header-line`.

```
awk '
    /header-line/ {
        ++part;
        if (output_file) close(output_file);
        output_file=sprintf("part-%03d.txt", part)
    }
    {print >output_file}
'
```

Comment: Gets me this after 17 files already: awk: part-017.txt makes too many open files - but I'm using awk on Mac, maybe it's different...

Comment: @Bernhard No, that was my bad, I wasn't closing the file. I fixed the code.

Comment: Awk doesn't have a `snprintf` function and I can't find any documentation for any implementation that does. Running this outputs: `awk: calling undefined function snprintf
 input record number 1, file
 source line number 5` when I run this on a Mac.

Comment: @Starfish Sorry, typo, that's `sprintf`